# Yii2 pagination doesn't change page

Tags: pagination, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My pager doesn't change to chosen page. When I click to the next page button it reloads the page. I also tried without `Pjax` container but the result was the same. I red the other posts but still can't figure it out. What I am doing is :

```
$categoriesProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Page::find()->where(['enable' => 1, 'id_in' => $page_id])->orderBy('sort ASC'),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 1,
                'route' => "/".Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('page')
            ]
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'categoriesProvider' => $categoriesProvider
        ]);
```

and in the view:

```
<?php Pjax::begin() ?>

    <div class="content-area col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">

        <?php if(!empty($categoriesProvider)){
            echo ListView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $categoriesProvider,
                'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}
                                \n<nav class='post-pagination col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>
                                    {pager}
                                </nav>",
                'itemView' => function($model, $key, $index, $widget){
                    return $this->render('_category', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]);
                },
                'pager' => [
                    'nextPageLabel' => ">>",
                    'prevPageLabel' => "<<",
                    'maxButtonCount' => 5,
                    'options' => [
                        'tag' => 'ul',
                        'class' => 'pagination',
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
        }?>
    </div><!-- Content Area /- -->

    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

URL configuration:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use backend\models\News;
use backend\models\Page;
use backend\models\Product;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

class SplitterController extends Controller
{
    public function actionManageRequest()
    {
        $param_page = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('page');
        $param_category = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('category');
        $param_product = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('product');

        $page = $this->getModel($param_page, new Page());

        //If page is existing page model go forward
        if(!empty($page)){

            $controller = $this->getController($page->view);

            if($this->checkId($param_page) === 'news'){
                $model = new News();
            }else{
                $model = new Page();
            }

            $category = $this->getModel($param_category, $model);

            if(!empty($category)){

                $product = $this->getModel($param_product, new Product());

                //If product is existing product model - go forward to single view
                if(!empty($product)){

                    $this->registerTags($product);

                    try{
                        return \Yii::$app->runAction("$controller/view");
                    }
                    catch (\Throwable $e){
                        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page not found',404);
                    }
                }

                //If product is not empty and product don't - throw exception
                if(!empty($param_product) && $product === null){
                    throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page out found', 404);
                }

                $this->registerTags($category);

                //If page model is news page - render news single view
                if($this->checkId($param_page) === 'news'){
                    return \Yii::$app->runAction("$controller/multi-view");
                }

                try{
                    return \Yii::$app->runAction("$controller/multi-view");
                }
                catch (\Throwable $e){
                    throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page not found',404);
                }
            }

            $this->registerTags($page);

            //If category is not empty but no such page found - throw exception
            if(!empty($param_category) && $category ===  null){
                throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page not found', 404);
            }

            return \Yii::$app->runAction($page->view);
        }

        //If page is not empty but no such page found - throw exception
        if(!empty($param_page) && $page ===  null){
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page not found', 404);
        }

        $page = Page::findOne(13);
        $this->registerTags($page);

        return \Yii::$app->runAction($page->view);
    }

    private function getModel($param, $model)
    {
        $chunks = explode('-', $param);
        $chunk_id = end($chunks);
        return $model::findOne($chunk_id);
    }

    private function registerMetaTags($name, $content)
    {
        \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
            'name' => $name,
            'content' => $content
        ]);
    }

    private function registerTitle($title)
    {
        \Yii::$app->view->title = $title;
    }

    private function checkId($param)
    {
        $id = explode('-', $param);
        $id = end($id);

        switch ($id) {
            case 14:
                return 'news';
                break;
            default:
                return 'page';
                break;
        }
    }

    private function getController($path)
    {
        $controller = explode('/', $path);
        return $controller[0];
    }

    private function registerTags($model)
    {
        $this->registerMetaTags('description', $model->meta_title);
        $this->registerTitle($model->meta_title);
    }
}
```

Url manager rules :

```
'rules' => [
                '<page>/<category>/<product>' => 'splitter/manage-request',
                '<page>/<category>' => 'splitter/manage-request',
                '<page>' => 'splitter/manage-request',
                '' => 'splitter/manage-request'
            ],
```

Comment: what is the name of the controller and action you want this pagination to work with, i recon you are providing the `route` incorrect as according to docs  **specifies the route that the URL to be created should use** so it shouldn't be just the parameter `page` you are setting it to here `'route' => "/".Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('page')`, it should be `controller/action` and you can use [`params`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-pagination#$params-detail) option for the parameters. check if it fixes the issue?

Comment: technically it should throw `404` in your current case

Comment: It doesn't work with `controller/action`. This is because of the way I am creating the url I guess. It gives me `404 not found`. In my way it doesn't returns error and the request goes through the right action but doesn't change the page. I mean it reloads it but still on page 1.

Comment: i don't get that. how are you creating the urls? because for me your configurations throw a `404` if I use your code as is

Comment: I've edited the post with the controller that manage the urls. All request goes though it. The url e.g. `categories-15` are combination of the page title and its id. I am saving it in the database. Sorry, but need to go away for a hour but will come back to see your conclusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Pagination` param conflict with your URL rules. `Pagination` uses `page` GET param to store current page number in URL. But your rules also uses `page` param and overrides param used by `Pagination`. You should use different param in your pagination config, to avoid conflicts:

```
'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 1,
    'route' => "/".Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('page'),
    'pageParam' => 'paginationPage',
]
```

See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-pagination#$pageParam-detail

---

Or you can rename params in your rules to avoid such problem also in other places:

```
'rules' => [
    '<r_page>/<r_category>/<r_product>' => 'splitter/manage-request',
    '<r_page>/<r_category>' => 'splitter/manage-request',
    '<r_page>' => 'splitter/manage-request',
    '' => 'splitter/manage-request'
],
```

Comment: Makes sense .. Will try as soon as I can and will return feedback :)

Comment: That was the problem :) Solved now. Thank you!